# Why is Mercurial ignoring some of my files?

Tags: mercurial

Having run 'hg init' and 'hg add' to create a new Mercurial repository and add the files, I find that quite a few of the files are not being tracked (they show up with 'hg status -i'), yet do not seem to match any pattern in my .hgignore file, so I don't see what the issue is. Here's the .hgignore file:

```
# Eclipse project files
.classpath
.project
.settings/

# IntelliJ project files
\.iml
\.ipr
\.iws
.idea/
out

# Grails files and dirs that should not be versioned
target
web-app/WEB-INF/classes
web-app/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld
web-app/WEB-INF/tld/fmt.tld
stacktrace.log
plugin.xml
devDb.*
prodDb.*

# Mac OS/X finder files
.DS_Store

oldhg/
```

All files in e.g., '/grails-app/views/layouts' are ignored, and yet I can see nothing in the .hgignore file which would cause this. What am I missing? How can I force these files not to be ignored?

Comment: I recommend using `syntax: glob` as long as you have a modern Mercurial and/or are not bothered by the performance difference seen in fairly-old Mercurial. Glob matches are easier for people to think about, and are implicitly anchored on name components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `out` matches anything containing that, including `layouts/`.  If you want it to only match at the beginning or end of a name, you need to anchor it with `^` or `$`.

Comment: Bingo! Knew it would be simple! So, to make sure I ignore everything in the 'out' directory, I'd presumably use `^out$`?

Comment: Mercurial does not ignore directories, it ignores files.  `^out$` will match a file named `out` in the root of the repository (and nothing else, because everything else is `out/something`, which does not match `^out$`).  If you want to ignore the directory, try `^out/`.

Comment: Ah, OK. I think I've got confused in the past, not realising there were two different syntaxes for .hgignore files, and using some examples with the wrong syntax. Am I right in thinking that the syntax is regex unless specified? So, if I want to ignore everything in a top level directory called `out`, I'd use `^out/`. Is that right?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html), regex is the default.